# Postgres: WHERE IN subselect with multiple columns?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to Postgres -- and it's been years since I've done anything SQL related so I'm perhaps over-thinking this -- but...

I have a subquery which selects a bunch of IDs (`cs_seed`) to perform another query on.

What I'd like to be able to do is to maintain the order from the subquery. I've searched for hours and discovered the `row_number()` feature which seems promising, but I obviously can't use this in a `WHERE IN` query as it's returning multiple columns.

```
SELECT ca_seed, ca_biome, ca_percent 
FROM colours_area 
WHERE ca_seed IN (SELECT cs_seed, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY cs_percent DESC) AS rn 
                  FROM colours_spawn 
                  WHERE cs_biome = 140 
                  ORDER BY cs_percent DESC LIMIT 10) 
ORDER BY rn DESC;
```

Is there any way I can do this? Or is my approach wrong?

Comment: Not quite sure why a simple JOIN wouldn't work here?

Comment: IN () select between parentheses must return only one column

Answer (score 1):

Use `join`?

```
SELECT ca.ca_seed, ca.ca_biome, ca.ca_percent 
FROM colours_area ca JOIN
     (SELECT cs_seed, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY cs_percent DESC) AS rn 
      FROM colours_spawn 
      WHERE cs_biome = 140 
      ORDER BY cs_percent DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) cs
     ON ca.ca_seed = cs.cs_seed
ORDER BY rn DESC;
```

This assumes that `cs_seed` only appears once in the subquery.  Otherwise, you might have to do more manipulation to deal with duplicates.

Comment: That's something similar to what I originally tried, but it's not producing the results that I know are correct when applying a `WHERE ca_seed IN ()` clause to the main query.

That's why I resorted to using the subquery to return the list of `cs_seeds` to then get the matching entries from the `colours_area` table. Duplication of results doesn't bother me, due to the relationships.